# How to disable database connection on specific page in a rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redis

I have a web service that receives requests and save them on redis database, and an another task that consolidates this requests on mysql database. Both process are completely separated, but if my mysql database isn't working my web service breaks down too.

I would like avoid this error, someone can help me?

My app is using Rails 4.2.6.

Thanks in advance.